# How can i get authorization to retrieve data from API Swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an API, but I got an error: "The given data was not valid JSON ", Status code: 401

I think that is an authentication problem. How can I set the auth credentials to make the GET request?

This is the code for retrieving the data from the JSON.

```
    func loadData()
    {
    guard let url = URL(string: getUrl) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, res, err in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([ItemsModel].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.items = result
                    }
                    
                   
                } else {
                    print(" No Data ")
                }
            } catch( let error)
            {
                print(res)
                print(String(describing: error))
            }
        
            
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

This is the code for the view :

```
struct GetView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
            List(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.year)
            }
            } .onAppear(perform: {
                viewModel.loadData()
                    
            })

            .navigationTitle("Data")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!` in the `if let data = data` at the top. What's the result? Any readable JSON? Paste whatever it is into the question.

Comment: "How can i set the auth credentials to make the GET request ?"  What type of authorization are you talking about?  Bearer authorization?  Basic authorization?

Comment: hello @George, this is what i got by printing the data " You do not have access rights for this scope"

Comment: @ElTomato Basic authorization

Answer (score 0):

To handle authentication you must implement a delegate for your URLSession:

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, challenge.proposedCredential)
    }
```

However, your 401 error may be due to your code not sending a valid GET request to the server. You probably want to decode the 'res' value to determine the status code:

```
if let response = res as? HTTPURLResponse {
    if response.statusCode != 200 {
        // data may be JSON encoded but you should get some for
        // statusCode == 401
    }
}
```

Without knowing the kind of service you are connecting to it is hard to speculate if you need a GET or a POST. The URL you use may require a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is the code for Basic Auth  :

```
func loadData() {
        
        //Credentials
        let username = ""
        let password = ""
        let loginString = "\(username):\(password)"
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
        
        //Request
        guard let url = URL(string: getUrl) else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        //Setup Session
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([ItemsModel].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.items = result
                    }
                    
                   
                }
                
                else {
                    print(" No Data ")
                }
            } catch( let error)
            {
               
                print(String(describing: error))
            }
        
        
       
    }
        task.resume()
        
}
```